# How to tell Facebook crawler to follow links?

Tags: curl, redirect, http-headers, web-crawler, facebook-opengraph

While browsers can automatically redirect the link if there is a location HTTP response header, Facebook Crawler cannot because it doesn't has an -L flag:

```
curl -v --compressed -H "Range: bytes=0-524288" -H "Connection: close" -A "facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)" "$URL"
```

Possibly this is the reason why [Open Graph checkers are unable to detect Open Graph data](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/what-makes-open-graph-checkers-unable-to-detect-open-graph-data/100261?u=ooker)

Unfortunately, my website is hosted in a shared hosting using Nginx, so it seems that I cannot modify the nginx.conf. But I use WordPress, if that helps.

Is there a way to tell it to automatically redirect too?